# Conversión de un loop for en un set()

Tags: python, optimización, eficiencia

Tengo el siguiente método que recorre un determinado fichero de entrada con una cantidad de datos que aumenta exponencialmente y devuelve una lista con las coordenadas de una ciudad.

El bloque de código que representa lo anteriormente expuesto es el siguiente:

```
def recorrido(puntos):
    for i in range(0, len(puntos)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(puntos)):
            objeto.add_recorrido(i, j, peso = distancia(puntos[i], puntos[j]))
    return objeto
```

El problema de dicho bloque es que recorrer con un `for` una lista con una cantidad de datos muy grande, tardará el doble de tiempo en recorrerla que hacerlo con un `set()` cuya eficiencia es mucho mayor. Por tanto, estoy buscando la manera de pasar el método anterior, en concreto, los bucles `for` a un `set()`.

Por otro lado, el siguiente bloque de código a optimizar está compuesto por una lista vacía en la que se almacenan el primer elemento de una tupla que está contenida en una lista y que los elemetos  repetidos, si ya se han introducido en la lista vacía, no se vuelvan a incluir.

```
C = [(0, 4), (4, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0)]
solution = []
for i, j in C:
  if i not in solution:
    solution.append(i)
return solution
```

Por ende, quiero llevar este bloque compuesto por `for` a otra funcionalidad mucho más eficiente, para que, de esta forma evitar la iteración manual del `for`. Traté de implementarlo por medio de un `set()` de la forma:

```
miListaSinRepeticion = list(set(listaoriginal))
sorted(miListaSinRepeticion)
```

Comment: Si no necesitas **todas** las distancias en una sola ejecución, puedes simplemente guardar las coordenadas y calcular la distancia sólo cuando la necesites. Revisa *lazy evaluation*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Aclaraciones

Tienes un pequeño lío con la idea de eficiencia en relación a los `set()`.

Primero, un `set()` no es una alternativa a un *loop*, ya que el `set()` es una estructura de datos, mientras que el *loop* es una estructura de control. El `set()` sería una alternativa a una lista, no a un *loop*.

Es cierto sin embargo que en ocasiones tener un `set()` en lugar de una lista te ahorra un bucle, ya que puedes verificar si un elemento dado pertenece o no al conjunto mediante la condición `elemento in conjunto`. En una lista, para ver si un elemento pertenece a la lista tendrías que hacer un bucle que itere por ella comparando los elementos uno a uno. Es cierto que Python admite también el operador `in` para las listas, por lo que podrías hacer `elemento in lista`, lo que parece ser equivalente al caso del conjunto, pero no es lo mismo. Para que python pueda responder `True` o `False` a la pregunta `elemento in lista`, tiene que iterar por todos los elementos de la lista hasta encontrar el solicitado. Sin embargo, en el caso de un conjunto, debido a la forma en que éstos están implementados internamente, puede responder a esa pregunta sin iterar.

En definitiva, testear si un elemento pertenece a un conjunto es muchísimo más eficiente que hacer lo mismo en una lista.

No obstante si tu algoritmo necesita recorrer uno a uno todos los elementos de tu colección (ya sea ésta una lista o un conjunto), porque tenga que hacer algo con cada uno de ellos, usar un `set()` ni te librará de hacer el bucle que itere, ni será más rápido que iterar por la lista, si tienen los mismos elementos.

A menudo los conjuntos se usan para eliminar duplicados en una lista. Cuando haces `sin_repeticiones = set(lista)`, el resultado es un conjunto que tiene los mismos elementos que esa lista, pero eliminadas las repeticiones. Esa instrucción equivale básicamente al siguiente bucle (y tiene la misma eficiencia):

```
sin_repeticiones = set()
for elemento in lista:
  if elemento not in sin_repeticiones:
    sin_repeticiones.add(elemento)
```

Hacer lo equivalente con listas, es decir, esto:

```
sin_repeticiones = list()
for elemento in lista:
   if elemento not in sin_repeticiones:
      sin_repeticiones.append(elemento)
```

sería más lento debido a la condición `elemento not in sin_repeticiones`, ya que para verificar si el elemento estaba o no ya en la lista se deben mirar todos los elementos que había (cosa que no es necesaria en un conjunto).

La principal desventaja de los conjuntos es que están *desordenados*. No hay un "primer elemento" en un conjunto. Cuando intentes iterar por los elementos del conjunto (o convertirlos de nuevo en una lista) te pueden salir en cualquier orden.

En este sentido el segundo bloque de código tiene una ventaja: mantiene el orden de la lista original. Es decir, la lista `sin_repeticiones` tendrá los elementos de la lista original, en el mismo orden en que aparecían, pero saltándose los repetidos.

En definitiva, si el orden de los elementos es importante un conjunto no sería el tipo de datos apropiado. Y si la mayoría de operaciones que haces sobre tu colección implica visitar sus elementos de uno en uno, el conjunto tampoco te va a dar ninguna ganancia de velocidad. Cuando los conjuntos son realmente útiles es cuando necesitas mirar a menudo si un dato estaba ya en tu colección o no, o cuando tienes que realizar operaciones entre los conjuntos, tales como obtener su unión, intersección, etc.

### Tu caso

Dicho todo lo anterior, no está del todo claro qué necesitas optimizar en el código. En tu bucle:

```
    for i in range(0, len(puntos)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(puntos)):
            objeto.add_recorrido(i, j, peso = distancia(puntos[i], puntos[j]))
```

ya que necesitas computar la distancia entre cada pareja de puntos (i,j), nada te va a librar de iterar por los elementos de la lista `puntos`, y convertirla en conjunto no traerá ninguna mejora (y sí problemas, ya que no habrá elemento i-ésimo ni j-ésimo en el conjunto).

Sin embargo ese bucle puede optimizarse si:

1. La lista `puntos` la haces más corta, por ejemplo eliminando duplicados en ella (para lo cual puedes usar cualquiera de los enfoques antes vistos). Probablemente esto no sea posible en tu caso.
2. Optimizas la función `distancia()` para que tarde menos (pues esta función, al ser llamada muchas veces, es tu cuello de botella). No muestras el código de esta función por lo que no es posible saber si podría optimizarse. Probablemente no.
3. Usas *memoización* para evitar llamar tantas veces a la función `distancia()`. Este truco consiste en que la función "recuerde" si ha sido llamada más veces con los mismos argumentos. Si por ejemplo llamas `distancia((0,0), (1,2))`, la función computará el valor necesario y te lo retornará, pero a la vez "recordará" ese resultado. Si más adelante vuelves a llamar a la función con los mismos parámetros `distancia((0,0), (1,2))` esta vez no calculará nada sino que retornará inmediatamente el valor "recordado"

La opción 3 parece interesante a la vez que compleja de implementar. En realidad sólo necesitas añadir una línea a tu código para implementarla, gracias a la biblioteca `functools`.

Basta que hagas un `from functools import lru_cache` y después pongas un decorador delante de tu función:

```
@lru_cache
def distancia(p1, p2):
  # ... tu implementación que no es necesario tocar
```

Ese decorador hace que la función recuerde llamadas anteriores y retorne resultados que ya hubiera calculado.